# Setting custom MongoDB BsonSerializer for all classes which inherit from base type

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

Is there a way to set a custom serializer for all types which inherit from a specific base type?

Given the following types:

```
class Identity<T> {
    T Value { get; set; }
}
class StringIdentity : Identity<string> {
}
class PersonIdentity : StringIdentity {
}
```

With the following model:

```
class Person {
    public PersonId Identity { get; set; }
}
```

And the following serializer:

```
class StringIdentitySerializer : IBsonSerializer<StringIdentity>
{
    object IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        return Deserialize(context, args);
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, StringIdentity value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteString(value.Value);
    }

    public StringIdentity Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        return new StringIdentity(context.Reader.ReadString());
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
    {
        Serialize(context, args, value as StringIdentity);
    }

    public Type ValueType => typeof(StringIdentity);
}
```

I figured that `BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(StringIdentity), new StringIdentitySerializer());` would serialize my property `Id` on `Person` as a string.

This serializer works when I change the `Id` property to be of type `StringIdentity`.

I understand why this is happening (`PersonIdentity` is not the same type as `StringIdentity`) but (without decorating the `Person` class) how would I get the property `Id` of type `PersonIdentity` on my `Person` class to serialize using this serializer?

Comment: No, we don't want questions like this in Jira. I'll answer here, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the way to do this is to register a [serialization provider](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/serialization/#serialization-provider). This will let you intercept all attempts to resolve an Identity and do whatever it is you want to do with them.